UnsupportedOperationException in drools from dummyconstraintBuilder class
I'm new to drools and I have added the following dependencies in my gradle file.
implementation("org.drools:drools-compiler:9.44.0.Final")

implementation("org.drools:drools-core:9.44.0.Final")

For a basic rules  drl file, I'm getting UnsupportedOperationException from dummyConstraintBuilder in drools.
We don't have an artifact for drools - expert in our nexus repository.
Can I get some guidance as to how to resolve this?
This is the error stack.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.ConstraintBuilder$DummyConstraintBuilder.setExprInputs(ConstraintBuilder.java:207)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.getExprBindings(PatternBuilder.java:1120)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.buildRelationalExpression(PatternBuilder.java:1105)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.buildExpression(PatternBuilder.java:983)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.buildCcdDescr(PatternBuilder.java:955)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:765)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.processConstraintsAndBinds(PatternBuilder.java:609)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:177)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:143)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:125)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.GroupElementBuilder.build(GroupElementBuilder.java:66)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.RuleBuilder.build(RuleBuilder.java:98)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.internalAddRule(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:339)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.addRule(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:334)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.compileRulesLevel(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:298)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.processors.ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.process(ImmutableRuleCompilationPhase.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4204)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.compileKnowledgePackages(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:461)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildRules(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:1020)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.doFirstBuildStep(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:994)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:114)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:104)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:270)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:216)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:80)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:282)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:248)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:195)


ConstraintBuilder builder = KieService.load(ConstraintBuilder.class); is returning Null.

Please share your "basic rules drl file" and how you load it. Plus the code where you're calling KieService.load(ConstraintBuilder.class) which is not at all a normal practice.

You can try to add the drools-mvel dependency.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
